# Variables- compiler doesn't care about the numbers I enter

Tags: java

I tried to make a basic program that will make some math calculations and I wanted it to use methods. At first it asks to enter two numbers and then it makes calculations, but I have no idea why it always returns "0" no matter what numbers I enter. What do I need to change in my code? so that my program would actually do these calculations.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Z1k7
{
static double a;
static double b;
static double sum;
static double difference;
static double product;
static double quotient;

public class Operations{

double sum (double a, double b){
    return a+b;
}

double difference (double a, double b){
    return a-b;
}

double product (double a, double b){
    return a*b;
}

double quotient (double a, double b){
    return a/b;
}}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This programme makes some calculations");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first number ");
    a = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the second number ");
    b = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("The sum: "+sum);
    System.out.println("The difference: "+difference);
    System.out.println("The product: "+product);
    System.out.println("The quotient: "+quotient);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the methods to perform the operations, you just print the values of variables which just hold their default values of `0`. Before you print the variables, set them.

```
System.out.println("This programme makes some calculations");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the first number ");
a = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter the second number ");
b = scan.nextDouble();

// --- New code ------------

// Since the operations are in a different class you need to 
// create an instance of that class
Operations ops = new Operations();

sum = ops.sum( a, b );
difference = ops.difference( a, b );
product = ops.product( a, b );
quotient = ops.quotient( a, b );

// end new code --------------

System.out.println("The sum: "+sum);
System.out.println("The difference: "+difference);
System.out.println("The product: "+product);
System.out.println("The quotient: "+quotient);
```

Also, since `Operations` doesn't really need an instance to perform these operations, you can create static methods:

```
public class Operations{

    public static double sum (double a, double b){
        return a+b;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then call them without creating an instance:

```
// --- New code ------------

sum = Operations.sum( a, b );
difference = Operations.difference( a, b );
product = Operations.product( a, b );
quotient = Operations.quotient( a, b );

// end new code --------------
```

Tutorials:

- [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)
- [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)
- [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 0):

A method like your

```
double sum (double a, double b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Has two values, a and b. These values are not related to the ones you have declared as

```
static int a;
static int b;
```

in you class. They are just named the same. This can cause confusion.

You have to *call* your method to make it do the actual calculation, like

```
int resultFromSummation = sum(a,b);
```

Here a and b are your class variables. These a and b are called *actual arguments*. They will be copied to the a and b inside the method (which are called *formal arguments).

I.e.

- you have to call the methods after you accept the input to a anb b.
- assign the result to a variable
- then output the result.